# An item with the same key has already been added - getting this error for SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, key

```
Select q1.*, q2.JobNumber
from (

select p.ProgramName, p.FulfillmentType, p.JobNumber, count(*) as [Counts]
from tProduction_AHFS p inner join tScanner s on p.ItemCode1 = s.ItemCode1
where (
       s.ScanStatusCode = 0
)
group by p.ProgramName, p.FulfillmentType, p.JobNumber
)

q1 inner join (

select p.ProgramName, p.FulfillmentType, p.JobNumber, count(*) as [Counts]
from tProduction_AHFS p inner join tScanner s on p.ItemCode1 = s.ItemCode1
where (
       s.ScanStatusCode <> 0
)
group by p.ProgramName, p.FulfillmentType, p.JobNumber

) q2 on q1.JobNumber = q2.JobNumber
```

An item with the same key has already been added - getting this error for SSRS 2008. SQL runs fine. but this error... where do i make changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming from the last line of your SQL code that table q1 has a "*JobNumber*" column?  Since you are returning **q1.***, you will be including *q1.JobNumber* along with *q2.JobNumber* -- SSRS doesn't like it when you return 2 columns with the same name.  Add an Alias for *q2.JobNumber* (i.e. ***q2.JobNumber AS Q2JobNumber***), and that will probably fix it.

Comment: thanks. I tried to the same but I was using q2.JobNumber AS JobNumber and not as Q2JobNumber. it worked. thanks.